# If differentiable then continuous (quick question)

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> If $f'(a)$ exists $\implies f$ continuous at $x=a$.

Translating this, for a function to be differentiable at $a$ it must first be continuous at $a$, but if it continuous at $a$ we can't be sure that it is also differentiable at $a$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is famously the case.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Many thanks

Comment: Banach proved in 1931 that in $C[0,1]$ a set of functions which are differentiable at at least one point is of the first Baire cathegory. So, this is a rare phenomenon in the world of continuoius functions to meet a differentiable one. Nevertheless, many functions we use in applications are nice (differentiable).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct. In many cases, differentiability is *defined* assuming you have a continuous function ("We say that a function $f$ continuous at a point $x_0$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if ..."), but this need not be the case. Note that the definition of differentiability of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$ requires the existence of the limit:

$$\lim_{dx\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+dx)-f(x_0)}{dx}$$

It is immediate that a necessary (but in general not sufficient) condition for this limit to exist is that $$\lim_{dx\to 0}f(x_0+dx)-f(x_0)=0$$

i.e. that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, since if this were not the case we'd have an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any arbitrarily small $\delta$ we'd be able to find some $dx$, with $|dx|<\delta$, such that $f(x_0+dx)-f(x_0)>\epsilon$ and thus a sequence of points $x_0+dx_i$ converging to $x_0$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x_0+dx_i)-f(x_0)}{dx_i}\right|\to\infty$.